# Amplify CDK with Next.js SSR

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a next.js (ssr) application in AWS' Amplify using the CDK but Amplify fails to identify the app as next.js ssr. When I do it manually though, using AWS UI, app is identified as SSR and works as expected.

[image]
This is generated by aws-cdk/aws-amplify v118 as:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as amplify from '@aws-cdk/aws-amplify';
import codebuild = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild');

export class AmplifyStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const sourceCodeProvider = new amplify.GitHubSourceCodeProvider({
            owner: '.....',
            repository: '....',
            oauthToken: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager('github-token'),

        });
        const buildSpec = codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObjectToYaml(
            {
                version: 1,
                applications: [
                    {
                        frontend: {
                            phases: {
                                preBuild: {
                                    commands: [
                                        "npm install"
                                    ]
                                },
                                build: {
                                    commands: [
                                        "npm run build"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            artifacts: {
                                baseDirectory: ".next",
                                files: [
                                    "**/*"
                                ]
                            },
                            cache: {
                                paths: [
                                    "node_modules/**/*"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        );
        const amplifyApp = new amplify.App(this, "cdk-nf-web-app", {
            sourceCodeProvider: sourceCodeProvider,
            buildSpec: buildSpec
        });

        amplifyApp.addBranch('develop', {
            basicAuth: amplify.BasicAuth.fromGeneratedPassword('dev')
        });
        amplifyApp.addCustomRule({
            source: "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
            target: "/index.html",
            status: amplify.RedirectStatus.REWRITE
        });
    }
}
```

Which is **identical** to what AWS has generated when I do it manually from UI. The difference here is the lack of Framework identification as shown in picture. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problems. No solution yet :-(

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, I was missing the role as without it aws won't create the necessary resources. (role: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html)

Edit to elaborate on how i fixed it:

Added a new role that can be used by amplify

```
const role = new iam.Role(this, 'amplify-role-webapp-'+props.environment, {
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('amplify.amazonaws.com'),
        description: 'Custom role permitting resources creation from Amplify',
    });
```

and assigned a policy (AdministratorAccess) that role

```
let iManagedPolicy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
        'AdministratorAccess',
    );
role.addManagedPolicy(iManagedPolicy)
```

Then upon creating the app, i assigned the role to the app:

```
const amplifyApp = new amplify.App(this, "cdk-nf-web-app", {
        sourceCodeProvider: sourceCodeProvider,
        buildSpec: buildSpec,
        role: role  <--- this line here
    });
```

Comment: Hi Panos! Could you elaborate a bit? What did you do?

Comment: Hello @Tobi , I updated the answer above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this should be in official docs

Answer (score 2):

The amplify app requires authorisation to create the relevant resources:

```
// This is for demonstrations purposes only; Do not give full access for production usage!
amplifyApp.grantPrincipal.addToPrincipalPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
    resources: ["*"],
    actions: ['*'],
}))
```

[Source Code Showcase](https://github.com/rdok/aws-cdk-amplify-nextjs-ssr/blob/d87c21fd967fd0d1d6c8424198b257be59062c78/infrastructure/lib/infrastructure-stack.ts#L33)

Comment: What would be the specific resources and actions here? Using wildcards looks a bit scary.

Comment: @Tobi the specific resources would be cloudfront for the CDN, s3 for the static assets and lambdas for the SSR pages. However, there isn't any clear way to get the corresponding fully qualified AWS resource logical ids to limit the IAM policies. What's really annoying is amplify next.js fails silently when it's missing them, so it's impossible to find out the required policies.

Comment: A way to find these resources is using AWS CloudTrail; the API logs provided by this service include the exact resource and action that was denied.